# Dynamically rendering polygons server-side?

Tags: maps, polygon, arcgis

I'm trying to implement a polygon based heatmap (i.e., instead of the color transitioning smoothly between two points, the color is the same within each polygon and changes across polygons).

The polygon color will tell the user which area's of the map are "good" and which are "bad". Similar to what these guys are doing here (http://illustreets.co.uk/explore-england/).

However, the color of the polygons will depend on the user input. Therefore, they have to be rendered dynamically. I don't think that the client will be able to handle the rendering, so the rendering will have to happen on the server.

I'm currently exploring ArcGIS as an option.

Does anybody know how to accomplish what I need in ArcGIS (or any other products)?

It would be best if I can find sample code that does something similar.

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of data structure are you "smoothing"?  From the looks of that site, they assign a color based on a "single" fact about each region -- i.e., the data is already averaged by the time you make your HTTP request.

Comment: yes, I think illustreets statically builds the shapes. We need more flexibility. The results will be customized per user's input. So the polygon layer will have to be built dynamically.

Comment: My point is that for the purposes of attaching a color to a polygon (say, the polygon who's "id" is 1337), they just need to look up a row in a database for the polygon.  If you need to actually do computation to summarize the data, that will be more expensive.  It will be that much more expensive if you can change the shape of the polygon, since you can't even know which data points to include in the statistics until you compute the statistic.  So you really do need to know what kind of data structure you will be making statistics for.

Comment: At this point, my main problem is not doing to computation for calculating the color of each polygon. It is rendering the polygon at the server dynamically. Let's assume that I have 20 polygons and I want the server to return a rendered image of all of the polygons each with a random color every time the user requests the page. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Based on our discussion in the comments, I can suggest the D3.js library.  It is designed to make dynamic visualization easy.

http://d3js.org/